# What's that book that ends with the preserved head of a political genius?

Tags: story-identification, novel, books

In this society, bisexuality is seen as fashionable. In the past, they perfected a method to accelerate equine pregnancy. That method is later used in humans, with the result that now humans grow up incredibly fast.

The protagonist is a government agent who is simultaneously researching mind-reading technology and head-preservation technology.

There's a terminally ill genius whose advice is always obeyed by government, and in the end they preserve his head and continue getting his advice by reading his mind. This upsets the genius immensely.

In this society, language has acquired a few quirks: money is now called "love," sex is now called "using," and someone with antiquated opinions is called an "obso."

Comment: I keyed in due to the subject line for the question - unfortunately, the answers "Walt Disney's biography" or *Futurama* (not a book, but come on, preserved heads?) don't really fit well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[The Tomorrow File](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/135908.The_Tomorrow_File)* by Lawrence Sanders

> In the not-so-distant future, planning takes the place of spontaneity
>   when it comes to sex, turning the bedroom into a chamber of terror. In
>   this society, the worst crime of all is to fall in love.

According to [reviews on goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/712103523?book_show_action=false) money is called "love", a sex partner - "user" and people born naturally are known as obsos (for obsolete).

From [The New York Times review](https://www.nytimes.com/1975/11/16/archives/the-tomorrow-file.html):

> Nicholas, an indefatigable “user” (lover), discovers sex and love are
>   not compatible. Among his projects is the head of a dog kept alive for
>   three years. The great thinker of the era, Hyman Lewisohn, is a dwarf,
>   dying of leukemia. Lewisohn's mind must be saved.